# Payflow Link Automatic Redirect

Tags: paypal, payflowlink

I'm using Payflow Link (not Payflow Gateway) and I'd like to automatically redirect the user back to my site after a successful transaction. Currently the user has to click on a button to go back to my site.  Is an auto-redirect supported by PayFlow Link?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to go into your Payflow Link Configuration settings within your account and set it to show the confirmation page on your website, and set the return URL.  This will redirect the buyer back to your site.